# find command not filtering files by size correctly

Tags: linux, bash, shell, linux-mint, shell-script

I am trying to filter `.out` and `.txt` files from sizes 8 to 15 bytes (not inclusive). The directory from which the files are searched is given as the first argument when calling the shell.

As input  have the directory temp:

```
my@computer:/$ ll temp
total 80
-rw-r--r-- 1 asistent users 17 May 25 19:04 file1.exe
-rw-r--r-- 1 asistent users 13 May 25 19:04 file1.out
-rw-r--r-- 1 asistent users 25 May 25 19:04 file1.pdf
-rw-r--r-- 1 asistent users  9 May 25 19:04 file1.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 asistent users 17 May 25 19:04 file2.exe
-rw-r--r-- 1 asistent users 25 May 25 19:04 file2.out
-rw-r--r-- 1 asistent users 25 May 25 19:04 file2.pdf
-rw-r--r-- 1 asistent users 13 May 25 19:04 file2.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 asistent users 25 May 25 19:04 file3.exe
-rw-r--r-- 1 asistent users  5 May 25 19:04 file3.out
-rw-r--r-- 1 asistent users  9 May 25 19:04 file3.pdf
-rw-r--r-- 1 asistent users 21 May 25 19:04 file3.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 asistent users 17 May 25 19:04 file4.exe
-rw-r--r-- 1 asistent users 17 May 25 19:04 file4.out
-rw-r--r-- 1 asistent users 29 May 25 19:04 file4.pdf
-rw-r--r-- 1 asistent users 25 May 25 19:04 file4.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 asistent users 13 May 25 19:04 file5.exe
-rw-r--r-- 1 asistent users  5 May 25 19:04 file5.out
-rw-r--r-- 1 asistent users  9 May 25 19:04 file5.pdf
-rw-r--r-- 1 asistent users  9 May 25 19:04 file5.txt
```

My script is:

```
#!/bin/bash


if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
        echo "USAGE: $BASH_SOURCE <SOURCE>"
        exit 1
fi

if [ ! -d $1 ]; then
        echo "Source directory does not exist"
        exit 1
fi

mkdir output

#filtering files here
allFiles=`find $1 -type f -size -15c -size +8c -iname "*.txt" -o -iname "*.out"`

#echo $allFiles

for file in ${allFiles[*]}; do
        #echo "Copying file $file"
        `cp $file output`
done
```

My output is:

```
total 40
-rw-r--r-- 1 181185 domain users 25 May 26 14:00 file1.out
-rw-r--r-- 1 181185 domain users  9 May 26 14:00 file1.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 181185 domain users 17 May 26 14:00 file2.out
-rw-r--r-- 1 181185 domain users 13 May 26 14:00 file2.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 181185 domain users  9 May 26 14:00 file3.out
-rw-r--r-- 1 181185 domain users  9 May 26 14:00 file3.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 181185 domain users  5 May 26 14:00 file4.out
-rw-r--r-- 1 181185 domain users 13 May 26 14:00 file4.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 181185 domain users  5 May 26 14:00 file5.out
-rw-r--r-- 1 181185 domain users  9 May 26 14:00 file5.txt
```

Notice i have files with sizes 17 and 25. Can some explain to me the proper usage of this command and my mistake?

Comment: [Bash pitfall number 1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29). Your `allFiles` is not an array even if you're trying to use it kinda like so. [Quote paremeters](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/108618). Why is `cp $file output` in backticks?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski because i thought that i have to have these commands in backticks. I just tried without them and it works. But do i have to have them when assigning the result of such operations to a variable?

Comment: [`$()` is better](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5778/108618). `$(bar)` (or the semi-equivalent version with backticks) gets substituted with `the_output_of_bar`, so `foo=$(bar)` is like `foo=the_output_of_bar` and this is how you assign output to a variable. But sole `$(bar)` is like `the_output_of_bar` where `the_output_of_bar` is *parsed and executed*. Very few commands produce output that is meant to be executed. Your `cp` in backticks was harmless because `cp` produces no output (possible error messages get to stderr and don't count as output). You executed `cp` *and* its empty output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In *find*, the 'OR' `-o` operator has lower precedence than the implied 'AND' between all other operators. So the condition is being evaluated as if it were this:

```
\( -size -15c -size +8c -iname "*.txt" \) -o \( -iname "*.out" \)
```

while you actually wanted this:

```
-size -15c -size +8c \( -iname "*.txt" -o -iname "*.out" \)
```

Comment: Thank you, i understand now. Just one more thing. Can you explain to me the syntax       \(expression\). Why is the first \ not in the parentheses? Or the second parentheses not before the \?

Comment: Oh that's a backslash for escaping. Nevermind.